# How to download an XML content to string variable from web address on Windows IoT

Tags: windows-iot

I have a calendar who's XML sharing link i want to be able to access and parse on my Windows 10 IoT app on Raspberry Pi. I can't figure out how to save this though.

Here's an example link:
https://sharing.calendar.live.com/calendar/private/eca6cd71-ae7c-4146-b7c1-a8f9d03de0d2/0ff376e0-b10d-4067-acde-71cd450283db/cid-60e973077a985b49/calendar.xml

Alternatively, if you have code where i can put in a Microsoft account name and password to iterate the associated calendar, that'd be fine too. I just need access to calendar events from my Microsoft Live account.

I tried using a webview to navigate to the address and running an invoke-script I've seen examples of elsewhere, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the `System.Net.WebClient` class... specifically the `DownloadString(Uri)` method, as in:

```
Var myWebClient as WebClient = new WebClient()
Var calendarUri as Uri = New Uri("https://sharing.calendar.live.com...")
Var result as String =  myWebClient.DownloadString(calendarUri)
```

(roughly)  :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction Jim! A little searching and I ended up with this which seems to work great!

```
imports system.net.http
    Public Sub Resync()
            Dim client As New HttpClient
            Dim resp = client.GetAsync(str_Link)
            str_RawXML = resp.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync.Result
        End Sub
```

Comment: Please mark your answer as accepted if you sorted it out and upvote, Jim?